# Transmit the Classname to a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, callback, this

I have different "Profiles" in a Json-File. In an index.html different profile cards are shown and filled with the information of the Json-File. When you click on a Profil (Profil-Card) a detailed profile.html will be loaded and the function initateProfile will be executed.

```
 $(document).on("click", ".profile-card", function () {
    $('#page-content').load("sections/profile.html", function () {
       initiateProfile($(this).data("profileid"));
    });
 });
```

I want to transmit the content of the profileid-class, which is the index for the Json-File.

```
function initiateProfile(id) {
  var profile_data;

  $.getJSON('data/profiles.json', function (data) {
     profile_data = data[id];
     $('.trn-name').text(profile_data.name);
     $('.trn-studies').text(profile_data.studies);
     $('.trn-stage').text(profile_data.stage);
  });
}
```

Unfortunatly the id-variable is undefined. So the function can't get the information of the Json-File. What's the problem?

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because `this` within the `load()` callback handler function is not the element which raised the event. It runs under a different scope. To fix this you need to save the element reference to a variable in the scope of the `click` handler, and use that within the callback, something like this:

```
$(document).on("click", ".profile-card", function () {
  var profileId = $(this).data('profileid');
  $('#page-content').load("sections/profile.html", function () {
    initiateProfile(profileId);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the `data-profileid` attribute is defined on the element which has the class `.profile-card`:

Your problem is `this`.

```
$(document).on("click", ".profile-card", function () {
  $('#page-content').load("sections/profile.html", function () {
    initiateProfile($(this).data("profileid")); // "this" points to the element with id "page-content"
  });
});
```

One solution would be to use `event.currentTarget`:

```
$(document).on("click", ".profile-card", function (event) {
  $('#page-content').load("sections/profile.html", function () {
    initiateProfile($(event.currentTarget).data("profileid"));
  });
});
```